# Using Promise.prototype.catch.apply(this, ...) : Why an unhandled Promise rejection?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'd like to write a wrapper around Promise.catch() that performs some default actions, like logging, and then calls .catch() to reject the Promise.

I am trying to understand the difference in behavior I'm seeing between these 2 simple bits of sample code.

Why doesn't this work:

```
declare global {
    interface Promise<T> {
        catchWrapper(): Promise<T>;
    }
}
export {}

Promise.prototype.catchWrapper = function(){
    return Promise.prototype.catch.apply(this, e => { console.log(`An error occured: {e}`) });
};

async function f(): Promise<string> {
    throw new Error('error');
}

f().catchWrapper()
```

but this does:

```
declare global {
    interface Promise<T> {
        catchWrapper(errHandler: (errObj: any) => void): Promise<T>;
    }
}
export {}

Promise.prototype.catchWrapper = function(){
    return Promise.prototype.catch.apply(this, arguments);
};

async function f(): Promise<string> {
    throw new Error('An error');
}

f().catchWrapper(e => { console.log(`An error occured: ${e}`) });
```

The first example is creating the lambda function inside of catchWrapper, this example generates an unhandled promise rejection.

The second example creates the lambda outside of catchWrapper and passes it in. This works as expected.

Am I seeing some kind of incompatibility with `this` and the lambda?

(I'm using typescript 3.1.2 and node 8.11.3)

**Edit**:
The first example works after putting the arrow function inside of an array like so:

```
return Promise.prototype.catch.apply(this,
    [e => { console.log(`An error occured: ${e}`) }]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arguments` is an array of arguments. So in your second example:

```
Promise.prototype.catchWrapper = function(){
    return Promise.prototype.catch.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

You are passing in arguments as an array, not as a function as you are maybe expecting. You can try passing in `arguments[0]` to get that function.

Or you could use a spread operator:

```
Promise.prototype.catchWrapper = function(){
    return Promise.prototype.catch.apply(this, ...arguments);
};
```

But the short answer is you are passing an array of arguments, instead of the arguments as separate parameters.

Comment: Wow, that was simple! I put [ ] around the lambda in the first example and now it works. Thanks a bunch!

I will accept your answer.

Comment: @MatBess Awesome! Glad it worked for you. The `arguments` variable is super cool, but also really weird to get your head wrapped around at first. But at the end of the day, just think of it as an array. And remember, it's connected to the `this` scope. So if you use arrow functions, `arguments` might not be what you expect.